Product of two derivatives
To find  $$a) \ \ \ \ \ \left ( \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} (1+x)^A\right ) (1+x)^B $$
I first derive what it is inside the brackets $A(1+x)^{A-1}$ and multiply it by $(1+x)^B$
I get $A(1+x)^{A-1+B}$
Then I try to find $$b)  \ \ \ \ \  \left ( \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}x \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(x+1)^A \right ) (1+x)^B$$
I do the same, find the derivatives inside the brackets, $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}x$ =1 and $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(1+x)^A = A(1+x)^{A-1}$. I multiply them and the result by $(1+x)^B$.
It gives the same result $A(1+x)^{A-1+B}$  , so I don't think it is right. How do you solve it?

Why do you think because they give the same result you must have done something wrong? Equation $b$ is just equation $a$ multiplied by $dx/dx$ which is just 1, so $b=a\cdot 1$, so the equations are equal, and you should indeed get the same result

I think it should be $$\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\left(x \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(x+1)^A \right )\right) (1+x)^B$$

If your question was
$$\left(\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}\right)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x+1)^A\right)(1+x)^B,$$
then yes, the answer $A(1+x)^{A-1+B}$ would have been correct.
But as the question says $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x$ instead of $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}$,the question is asking to find $$\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x+1)^A\right)\right)(1+x)^B,$$
which on solving $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x+1)^A$
simplifies to $$\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(Ax(x+1)^{A-1}\right)\right)(1+x)^B.$$
We can take $A$ out of differentiation as it is a constant so it becomes $$A \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x(x+1)^{A-1}\right)\right)(1+x)^B.$$
Now by using chain rule of differentiation, we get
$$A \left((x+1)^{A-1}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}+x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x+1\right)^{A-1}\right)(1+x)^B,$$
which simplifies to $$A \left(\left(x+1 \right)^{A-1}+\left(A-1 \right)x \left(x+1 \right)^{A-2}\right)(1+x)^B.$$
On further simplification, we get our answer
$$A(x+1)^{A+B-1}+A(A-1)x(x+1)^{A+B-2}.$$
